# I want to automatically logout a user when he/she closed the browser and if he/she clicked the back button of the browser

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

**my logout.php code**

```
<?php 
 $past = time(0); 
 setcookie(ID_my_site, gone, $past); 
 setcookie(Key_my_site, gone, $past); 
 header("Location: index.php"); 
 ?>
```

what i need to add in this code in order to logout a user when he/she closed the browser and if he/she clicked the back button of the browser??

**my login.php code**

```
<?php 
$page = "login";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nell");
 if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
 { 
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
        {
        if ($pass != $info['password']) 
            {                       }
        else
            {header("Location: members.php");}
        }
    }
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) 

    { header("Location: error.php");}

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
 $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
 if ($check2 == 0) 

    { header("Location: error2.php");}

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))     
 {
 $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
    $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) 

        { header("Location: error3.php");}

     else 
 { 
     $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
     $hour = time() + 3600; 
 setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
 setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);   
 header("Location: members.php"); 
 } 
 } 
 } 
 else 
{    }
 ?>
```

Please help, I want to automatically logout a user when he/she closed the browser and if he/she clicked the back button of the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can't determine in PHP when the user closes the browser - as far as PHP is concerned, then the page is sent to the user, PHP is done with it.

Instead of using cookies, you *could* use sessions to get a better contact with the user machine. You could do something like setting the session timeout to only a few minutes, but this will run the risk that someone who is a slow reader or takes their time moving from page to page will be locked out.

If you want to be a real meanie when it comes to user logouts, you might have to do something like javascript'ing in a regular "check-in" that sends data to the server to keep the session alive - this along with a short session time might sort-of achieve the result you are looking for.

Edit: the code you posted also shows old `mysql_*` functions, along with root user and no password to access the database. Please dead god tell me you just inserted that user as a placeholder. Secondly, please move on to PDO or mysqli to avoid getting your website hosed by the first annoyed user that comes along.

You aren't even checking for `$_POST` data that contains a username of "bob; drop table users;" which means I could pop that in and your website is *kaput*. Google SQL Injection, fix your code. Right now. Seriously.

Edit 2: As Adnan points out, you could set your cookie expiry date to `0` which will only keep it as long as the session is open. I generally think that keeping a username in a cookie is great, but leaving a password to be entered in by the user is better for securitym you could take this approach as well.

Edit 3: based on your code:

```
<?php 
    $page="logout"; 
    $security=true; 
    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) || $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] < time()+3600) 
    { 
        session_destroy(); 
        $_SESSION = array(); 
    } 
    $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 3600; 
    header("location: login_admin.php"); 
?>
```

Why not just set a session variable along the lines of:

```
$_SESSION['isAdmin']=true;
```

when they log into the admin functions and change it to `false` when they log out of the admin functions? No need to kill off the entire session, just change a single variable kept in it.

Comment: One can also set the the cookie expiry time to `0`, meaning it will expire by the end of the session (when the browser closes).

Comment: @Adnan Interesting, thanks for that info, I have always used cookies to store long term info, nothing short term. Editing answer.

Comment: Okay heres the problem.. i have a admin user and a member user.. I have the same code for login and logout for the admin and the user. So the problem is when i log in to the admins page and at the same time i login into the user, when anyone of user or admin logouts, all of them will be logged out, I used session for admin and user so I did was, i change the code for user to not be affected if the user or admin logged out.

Comment: @jolomendoza Sounds like you are paying for some quick/lazy code. If you want to ensure that an admin is logged out, but the user is still logged in, you will *have* to change your logout code to include something like "log me out from admin functions only" rather than dropping the whole user session/cookie.

Comment: ahhh okay.. only the logout code i need to edit for the user? would it affect the admins logout page too??


heres my logout code for admin

<?php 
$page="logout";
$security=true;
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) || $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] < time()+3600) {

session_destroy();

    $_SESSION = array();
}
$_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 3600;

header("location: login_admin.php");
?>

Comment: @jolomendoza See edit 3.

Comment: OKay thanks for that info.. Ill took your suggest for cookies thank you so much.

Comment: @jolomendoza Look into the third edit more than the cookies mate. That's the one that really gets at the crux of the matter!

Answer (score -1):

you could use the javascript unload event as a trigger to post back to your PHP code.

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Unload is called with every step the user makes away from the page, which includes reloads and clicking links. This might be a little *too* gung-ho. You don't want the user clicking a valid link on the page (to move to some other aspect of the site) and being logged out. Short of a page where ALL the user interaction is done through jquery, this probably won't work.